# Grabbing pollen type from Wunderground using JSoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently attempting to scrape Wunderground's Pollen website (as their API doesn't at the moment support pollen data).

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wunderground.com/DisplayPollen.asp?Zipcode=19104").get();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Element levels = doc.select("td.levels").get(i);
    Element dates = doc.select("td.text-center.even-four").get(i);
    levelsList.add(levels.text());
    datesList.add(dates.text());
}
```

Attached above is the code that I used to capture the pollen index and the day it was capture.

I am currently trying to capture pollen type, an example of the HTML is below.

[image]

Using `div.panel`:

`Element pollenType = doc.select("div.panel").first();`

It *does* scrape the Pollen Type, but it also scrapes the entire panel of the page, meaning it captures more data than I want. I am only interested in this: `Pollen Type: Oak, Birch and Maple.`

Which branch do I have to capture? Or, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in the content of the heading you could select:

```
doc.select("div.panel h3").first().text()
```

Comment: Or even just `doc.select("h3").first().text()` though of course that doesn't permit any other `<h3>`-tags.